# Matrices and vectors with quaternion elements

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

Are matrices and vectors with quaternion elements useful for anything?

I built a linear algebra package in Java that can have real, complex, rational and/or quaternion elements. Quaternions are supported simply because that class implements the same interfaces as the other scalar/element classes.

I know something about what quaternions can be used for (graphics, robotics...) but I do not know how exactly how they're used in those cases. What kind of data structures are they put into, and how would one operate on those data structures.

Can it make sense do matrix multiplication (or calculate some decomposition) using matrices with quaternion elements?

Comment: Opinion-based? Is that kind of questions allowed here? ~ Probably.

Comment: Quaternions represent rotations in $3$-space, just as complex numbers represent rotations in the plane. I've seen them used by engineers for robotics problems.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyones opinion! Asking for facts. Can this be used to model "anything"?

Comment: I know something about what quaternions can be used for. But putting them in a matrix (as elements) and then do matrix multiplication, decompositions, solve equation systems...

Comment: Why not to use quaternions as elements - as submatrices can be also used as elements of bigger matrices? Quaternions btw can also be represented by $4 \times 4$ matrices I suppose...

Comment: Probably in SLERP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp  to have vectors with quaternions would be useful..

Comment: Clifford algebras can be used to describe spinors in higher dimensions, and they are isomorphic to matrix algebras over reals, complex numbers or quaternions (possibly their split versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are useful, certainly in pure mathematics, and also theoretical physics (I don't know much about engineering).  Here is a rough idea.

The most direct way quaternions are "useful" is to use quaternions to represent SO(3), the group of rotations about the origin in 3-space (which comes up in various engineering problems including robotics).  If you want to think in terms of matrices and vectors, the rotations are given by invertible (i.e., nonzero) 1-by-1 quaternionic matrices (up to scalars in $\mathbb R^\times$) and the 3-d representation space is the space of vectors of length 1 of pure quaternions.

SO(3) is called a (special) orthogonal group, and you can use certain subsets of matrices over the quaternions to represent higher-dimensional orthogonal groups as well.  For instance, SO(5) (rotations about the origin in a 5-dimensional real vector space) can be represented by a certain subset of 2-by-2 matrices over the quaternions.  (It is something like the
set of invertible $g \in M_2(\mathbb H)$ such that $\bar g^T g = I$ up to scalars, where the bar denotes componentwise conjugation and $T$ is transpose, though I am going of memory here so this might be slightly off.)
These should then act as rotations by matrix multiplication on a certain (sub)space of quaternionic vectors of length 2.